# Getting started with Extjs.Net with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

i am windows form developer but suddenly shifted to asp.net with extjs.Net. i Refered to [EXT.NET](http://www.ext.net/) samples which shows only the UI, But i am unable to find the data exchange between code behide and UI such as databinding.Please suggest some sample, link or any other material form which i can start the development..

I am using simple asp.net not MVC

Comment: Do you require help connecting Ext.NET markup code to a data source? or, are you using just ExtJS JavaScript and require help connecting to a data source? Based on your description it's just a little unclear.

Comment: @ mcgill: i require help connecting Ext.NET markup code to a data source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please suggest some sample, link or any other material form which i can start the 
>   development.

Here are some you could read:

- http://extaspnet.codeplex.com/
- http://examples.extjs.eu/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/286794/Using-ExtJs-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best place to start with Ext.NET is browsing through the [Ext.NET Examples Explorer](http://examples.ext.net). There are several hundred full scenarios provided and several dozen dealing directly with connecting to various data sources, including standard **ASP.NET** `DataSource` Controls.

Here's a relatively basic sample demonstrating connecting to an `<asp:SqlDataSource>`

http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/DataSource_Controls/SqlDataSource/

Lots of options are available for connecting to just about any form of data endpoint. If you have more specifics regarding your requirements, I'd be happy to assist, or point you in the right direction.

Hope this helps.